Catch block not catching file load faillure when file is blocked by applocker / wdac
try
            {
                var appcontrolHeartbeat = new Class1();
            }
            catch (FileLoadException e)
            {
                log.Info(
                    $"AppcontrolHeartbeat.dll was blocked. This file is intentionally added to generate a heartbeat signal. Caught by FileLoadException");
 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info($"AppcontrolHeartbeat.dll was blocked. This file is intentionally added to generate a heartbeat signal. Caught by {ex.Source}");
            }

The generation of new Class1 fails on devices that have applocker or Windows Defender Application Control is enforced. It's ok that the new Class1 call fails, it is intentional to make sure Application allowlisting is functional.
However for some reason the code above throws an unhandled exception which is puzzling to me and not what I am trying to achieve. The exception seems clearly handled to me. I want the code with a bunch of steps after this part.
Anyone have an idea why this would be treated as unhandled? This is a dotnet core app should that make a difference.
Thanks,
Kim
.\WDACEventLogCollectorCore.exe
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\UserProfile\OneDrive\WDACLogCollectorCore\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\AppControlHeartbeat.dll'. Your organization used Device Guard to block this app. Contact your support person for more info. (0x800711C7)
File name: 'C:\Users\UserProfile\OneDrive\WDACLogCollectorCore\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\AppControlHeartbeat.dll'
at WDACEventLogCollector.Program.Main(String[] args)

and what's the code for Class - constructor/static constructor?

There's no real constructor, the whole idea is that the dll of that class is loaded by instantiating it. Class code is: Public Class Class1 {}

It appears however that the dll is loaded for one reason or another before the new Class1() code is reached.

so Class1 really lives as a type in the dll that fails to load?

Yes, it does, and it's the only thing that lives in there.

okay, I suggest you edit your questions with the exact purpose of the class and the dll. Maybe this example about AssemblyResolve event will be helpful until somebody answers.
